# Numpy argwhere inequality conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a numpy array `np_array` that is 3000x100.  If I wanted to find the indices where the elements were greater than 1, I would do:

```
np.argwhere(np_array > 1)
```

Now say I have a 3000x101 matrix, and I want to find all elements where in the first 100 columns, an element was greater than 1, and for the corresponding row in the last column, the element was less than 0, is there some numpy way to do it without writing loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a boolean array representing which rows had an element greater than 1 in the first 100 columns:

```
numpy.any(np_array[:, :100] > 1, axis=1)
```

and an array representing which rows had an element less than 0 in the last column:

```
np_array[:, 100] < 0
```

and perform an element-wise AND operation of those two arrays:

```
numpy.any(np_array[:, :100] > 1, axis=1) & (np_array[:, 100] < 0)
```

to get a boolean array of shape `(3000,)` representing which rows fit your criteria. If you want, you can then `argwhere` that to get indices:

```
numpy.argwhere(numpy.any(np_array[:, :100] > 1, axis=1) & (np_array[:, 100] < 0))
```

Comment: So what I want is a boolean array of shape (3000, 100) where it's not whether some row has some element in it satisfying, but which shows exactly which element in each row satisfies.

Comment: @AlexanderMoreno: That was not clear from your description. It's still not clear what you mean from your comment. Could you give an unambiguous specification?

Comment: @Alexander, use the code from this answer but without the `numpy.any`